# Bootstrap template, css background color not covering div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build my one page design but whenever I try to change the color of a `div` it just results in a small box.

HTML:

```
<div class="sec1 clearfix">
    <div class="row">
        <h2 class="push_3">About Us</h2>
        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sec1 {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    display: block;
}
```

All im getting https://i.stack.imgur.com/53yZA.jpg

Comment: Your code its ok. Are you getting any errors in console about the included css file ?

Comment: Your code works in JSFiddle

Comment: it's because you have set a height - try use min-height instead

Comment: Still not working see the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.sec1 {
height: 200px;
background-color: red;
width: auto;
background-repeat: repeat;
position:absolute;
}
.sec1 .row{
  postion:relative; 
  border:1px solid red;
  color:green;
 }
```